# Calling PHP when running HTML locally not echoing strings

Tags: php, html

I like to test my Javascript by running on my local drive to avoid having to upload to my web page each time I make changes.  In my HTML file I just use full paths to point to PHP files on my web page.  Haven't had a problem until I ran into this.  The PHP file below runs fine if I run the HTML file from my web page.  But if I run the HTML file from my local drive, only the first part of the PHP file works.  The foreach block does not - or it's just not echoing the strings.

I've tried using the full path to the folder rather than just ".txt" below even though it seems that shouldn't be necessary as the PHP is run at the server end.

I tried other methods of reading files in a directory in case the "glob" useage was the problem when running on my local drive.

I even did away with all the commands within the foreach block and just put an echo statement there, but nothing appeared.

I'm guessing an echo statement doesn't work when the PHP file is called from an HTML file on a local drive?

Tried innerHTML with a  but that didn't work - or I'm not doing it correctly.

```
<?php
$MSG=$_GET["myFile"];
$fh = fopen($myFile, "w") or die("can't open file");
$MSG=$_GET["jsVar"];
fwrite($fh, $jsVar);
fclose($fh);

foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
  echo $filename;
  echo "<br />";
  $file = fopen($filename, "r");
  while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    echo $line . "<br />";
  }
  fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: your foreach can be simplified like this: `nl2br(file_get_contents($filename))` instead of all of this `$file = fopen($filename, "r");
  while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    echo $line . "<br />";
  }
  fclose($file);`

Comment: Wow-I tried it.  Much better format!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't support PHP, you must install XAMPP to run it through localhost.

Comment: Or any other PHP server instance, such as Apache

Comment: Yes, XAMPP has Apache in it's package.

Comment: I know that, I am just adding that comment so he knows there are other solutions available

Comment: Just downloaded it. Sounds like an easy approach to using Apache. I was hoping since my other PHP code is working from HTML running directly from my local drive that there would be a workaround for echoing strings to the document.  But this sounds like the better approach all around.  Thanks.